# Eclipse 3.7 Required Plug-ins

Tags: eclipse, jar, eclipse-plugin

I am currently running Eclipse 3.7 Indigo
My current project is a Plug-in Project

I wanted to try out the product called icePDF in my existing project.
So I downloaded the two required jar files from the binary download.
icepdf-core.jar and icepdf-viewer.jar

So I created a new plug-in project from existing jars.  I am added the two jar files and created the plug-in project.  I then exported the project and produced a project jar file .

Went back in to my existing project where I want to use the features of icePDF.
Went to dependencies -> Required Plug-ins -> Added my new icePDF plugin.

I am sure that I am missing a key step.  Because as soon as I close the icePDF project in Package Explorer.  I get a error in my main project.

Error : Missing Required Plug-in

What I don't understand is I have at least 12 other required plug-ins, none of them are open.

Was this the right way to try and add the icePDF jars to my existing project?  Was there a way to just incorporate the jars in to the plug-in project without having to create the new project?

***EDIT***
Looks like icePDF primarily uses Swing.  My project is SWT based, I do not want to use Swing in the project. I am looking for something that will view a existing pdf, convert a pdf and print a pdf to local printer.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behavior that Eclipse reports an error when a required plugin is closed, if this plugin is only available through your workspace. I assume that the other required plugins are 'standard' Eclipse plugins, such as EMF; those do not have to be in your workspace, as they are directly installed into your Eclipse platform.

Another way would be to put the original Jars into your plugin project. Just create a folder, e.g. `lib/`, paste the Jars there, and add them to the plugin project's class path. The latter is a bit tricky, as you have to add them in the Project Properties as well as in the `Manifest.ml` (in the 'runtime' tab of the plugin.xml-editor, IIRC) and the `build.properties` file.

Answer (score 1):

Please read about the [Eclipse target platform](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseTargetPlatform/article.html), as you seem not to be aware of that concept.

Generally speaking, there is an Eclipse environment in which you develop your code (which *you* use), and there is another Eclipse environment, in which your developed plugin *runs* (i.e. which a user of your plugin uses). That second one is called "target platform" in Eclipse terms. And they can be different, e.g. you develop in Eclipse 4.2, but your plugins shall run in Eclipse 3.7.

If you don't create a target platform yourself, then Eclipse just assumes its current installation to be the target platform (i.e. your development environment). That is why all "normal" plugins can be used as dependencies without them being in the workspace. But your icePdf plugin is not part of the Eclipse installation (and therefore not part of the target platform), which is why it needs to be available in the workspace.

If you define a target platform, you can then simply add those icepdf plugins to it and don't need to have them in the workspace any longer.